# How to kill old thread after using timertask and called new method?

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi guys, I'm new to Java and I'm takin a course at Uni. I have gotten a task to write a small game that generates a random nr that the player will guess. After guessing the player is supposed to get the option to play again or WAIT and automatically come back to the main menu.

First I tried `thread.sleep(5000)` but it got stuck because it was waiting for user input (nextLine). Then a friend told be about timer and timertask, which i used and now my game is almost working.

The only problem is when i call a new method from my `run()` method the old (play again Y/N) thread running in the background is not ended. So when my menu appears after 5 seconds, my first input is connected to the play again Y/N choice and not the main menu options. Here are the kod parts:

```
public void tryAgain() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Task timerTask = new Task();
    int y = 1;
    String yesNo = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Try again Y/N");
    Statistics.setGames(games);
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000);

    do {
        try {

            yesNo = sc.nextLine();
            if (yesNo.equals("Y") || yesNo.equals("y")) {
                guesses = 0;
                y = 2;
                timerTask.cancel();
                playGame();


            } else if (yesNo.equals("N") || yesNo.equals("n")) {
                y = 3;
                timerTask.cancel();
                Statistics.setGames(games);
                menu.showMainMenu();

            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong input, try Y or N:");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            sc.next();

            System.out.println("Wrong input, try Y or N:");

        }

    } while (y == 1);

}
```

and :

```
import java.util.TimerTask;

class Task extends TimerTask {

    play menu = new play();

    public void run() {

        Statistics.getGames();

        menu.menu.showMainMenu();

        cancel();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interrupt blocking reads. But you can use the `BufferedReader.ready()` method, which will tell us whether the underlying stream is ready to be read.

Let's implement a non blocking reader:

```
public class OurNonBlockingConsoleReader implements Callable<String> {

    public String call() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader sysInReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String answer;
        do {
            System.out.println("Try again Y/N");
            try {
                while (!sysInReader.ready()) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                answer = sysInReader.readLine();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return null;
            }
        } while (!"y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && !"n".equalsIgnoreCase(answer));
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Next, we call this reader with a timeout, using the `ExecutorService` and the `Future` from `java.util.concurrent` package:

```
public void tryAgain() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService readerExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<String> readerResult = readerExecutor.submit(new OurNonBlockingConsoleReader());
    try {
        String answer = readerResult.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            playTheGame();
        } else {
            goToMainTheMenu();
        }
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        goToMainTheMenu();
    } finally {
        readerExecutor.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

The `readerResult.get(...)` call will wait 5 seconds for a valid answer. It there is no valid answer returned from `OurNonBlockingConsoleReader.call`, the `Future.get` will raise a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: Im really thankfull for the answer, but since Im on a very basic level, it is difficult to understand all the processes in your code :) i would not know how to explain or comment to my teacher

Comment: I tried the code you sent, it worked perfect the first time, if i then play the game again and try to press Y to play again(3rd time) it does not want to accept my first input? Since i dont understand the code i cant find out why, like the first time the tryAgain method is called, this is very strange. Could you please try to explain, i really appreciate you taking your time

Answer (score 0):

Addressing only your immediate problem:

Your run method needs to set `y` to something other than 1 (perhaps 0), then call `interrupt` on Y/N thread.  This will kick it out of a blocking read  with an InterruptException or ClosedByInterruptException.  (Your `catch` block will need to be smarter.)  Then the Y/N loop will finish because `y` is not 1.  End of problem.

For this to work, `y` needs to be declared `volatile`, or each thread *might* use its own copy.  (Accessing it only within synchronized blocks will work also.)

Added Example:

```
public class YesNo  {
    private volatile Thread  tryAgainThread;
    private volatile int     y = 1;

    public doNotTryAgain()  {
        y = 0;
        tryAgainThread.interrupt();
    }
    //  Called only from tryAgainThread thread.
    public void tryAgain()  {
        do  {
            try {
                // Exactly what you have now.
                ...
            }
            catch (Exception e)  {}
        }  while (y == 1);
    }
....

class Task extends TimerTask  {
    public YesNo  ynInstance;
    ...
    public void run()  {
        ynInstance.doNotTryAgain();
        Statistics.getGames();
        ...
    }
}
```

I'll let you figure out how to set `tryAgainThread`, which is the thread the `tryAgain` method is called--and is looping--on.  Also, Task needs to know the relevant (and probably only) instance of the class that contains the `tryAgain` call running in the 'tryAgainThread'.  In your case some static public fields will do the job, but ideally you'd want something more elegant.

Also, `catch (Exception e)  {}` will work fine, but ideally you'd check your exceptions better.

Comment: Thanks alot bro its just that im too new to java to figure it out, cant understand why we get such a task so early on, everyone in my class is stuck on the same problem

Comment: Hope I helped.  That is a brutal problem.  Multithreading is extemely advanced stuff.